# Create equivalent paths in Django urls.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-urls

I am attempting to create 2 url prefixes that would be equivalent in my app (this is due to some aesthetic user requirements), and am unsure the best way to go about this. The most straightforward option would be to create another set of `urlpatterns` with the alternate prefix. However, this would be repetitive and make maintenance more difficult. Is there a simpler way to make `foo/<str:key>/` equivalent to `bar/<str:key>` and `staff/<str:key>/` equivalent to `foo/<str:key>/staff/`?

#### Current URLS

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('foo/<str:key>/welcome/', views.welcome),
    path('foo/<str:key>/dashboard/', views.dashboard),
    path('foo/<str:key>/staff/dashboard/', views.staff_dashboard),
]
```

#### Desired Patterns

```
urlpatterns = [
    # Original paths
    path('foo/<str:key>/welcome/', views.welcome),
    path('foo/<str:key>/dashboard/', views.dashboard),
    path('foo/<str:key>/staff/dashboard/', views.staff_dashboard),

    # Alternate paths to the same pages
    path('bar/<str:key>/welcome/', views.welcome),
    path('bar/<str:key>/dashboard/', views.dashboard),
    path('staff/<str:key>/dashboard/', views.staff_dashboard),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the set of paths once, and then include these twice:

```
from django.urls import include, path

sub_paths = [
    path('welcome/', views.welcome),
    path('dashboard/', views.dashboard),
    path('staff/dashboard/', views.staff_dashboard),
]

urlpatterns = [
    path('foo/<str:key>/', include(sub_paths)),
    path('bar/<str:key>/', include(sub_paths)),
    path('staff/<str:key>/dashboard/', views.staff_dashboard),
]
```

We thus define the paths for `foo/` and `bar` *once* in a single list, and then reuse these multiple times.

That being said, it is advisable that each view (with parameters) maps to a single path and vice versa. It makes it clear that two different paths will go to different views, and when reversing the view, it is clear what the outcome will be.

Comment: Brilliant! This is exactly what I needed. This is hopefully just a temporary fix required as we migrate to a different domain name and have to straddle users within the two domains for a bit. What are the specific risks that we should be looking out for having 2 paths map to the same view?

Comment: @wraasch: well you probably want to name your parameters the same, so not `foo/<str:a>/` and `bar/<str:b>/`, since then you call the same view with parameters that have a different name. Furthermore if you reverse the view with `reverse(..)`, or `{% url ... %}` it will normally take the first that matchres, so in this case, through `foo/`.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for your help!